# Using Gstreamer to stream RTSP camera to AWS Kinesis

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, amazon-kinesis

I am not beign able to stream my camera to kinesis. It seems that the stream is being sent to the server but the Kinesis Stream is not accepting it for some reason.

When I try this command:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:bachir123@192.168.15.6:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! kvssink stream-name=YourStreamName storage-size=128 access-key="YourAccessKey" secret-key="YourSecretKey" aws-region="eu-west-1"`

I get this:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> log4cplus:ERROR could not open file ../kvs_log_configuration
> INFO - createKinesisVideoClient(): Creating Kinesis Video Client
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] INFO - heapInitialize(): > Initializing native heap with limit size 134217728, spill ratio 0% > and flags 0x00000001
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] INFO - heapInitialize(): Creating > AIV heap.
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] INFO - heapInitialize(): Heap is initialized OK
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - getSecurityTokenHandler invoked
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - Refreshing credentials. Force refreshing: 0 Now time is: 1682300235971950593 Expiration: 0
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] INFO - createKinesisVideoStream(): Creating Kinesis Video Stream.
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] INFO - logStreamInfo(): SDK version: 8867047d8d8f56645009ed73788a57f0a6107772
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo(): Kinesis Video Stream Info
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Stream name: camera_1
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Streaming type: STREAMING_TYPE_REALTIME
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Content type: video/h264
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():     Max latency (100ns): 600000000
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Fragment duration (100ns): 20000000
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Key frame fragmentation: Yes
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Use frame timecode: Yes
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Absolute frame timecode: Yes
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Nal adaptation flags: 0
> 2023-04-23 22:37:15 [3069628160] DEBUG - logStreamInfo():   Average bandwith (bps): 4194304
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] INFO - getStreamingEndpointResultEvent(): Get streaming endpoint result event.
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] DEBUG - getStreamingTokenHandler invoked
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] DEBUG - Refreshing credentials. Force refreshing: 1 Now time is: 1682300237767324378 Expiration: 18446744073709551615
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] INFO - getStreamingTokenResultEvent(): Get streaming token result event.
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] DEBUG - streamReadyHandler invoked
> 2023-04-23 22:37:17 [2877289536] Stream is ready
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Progress: (open) Opening Stream
> Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
> Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
> Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://admin:bachir123@192.168.15.6:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
> Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
> Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
> Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0

> WARN - curlCompleteSync(): curl perform failed for url https://s-5ac447c0.kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/putMedia with result Timeout was reached: Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] WARN - curlCompleteSync(): HTTP Error 0 : Response: (null)
> Request URL: https://s-5ac447c0.kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/putMedia
> Request Headers:
> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*CREDENTIALS*/20230424/eu-west-1/kinesisvideo/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=connection;host;transfer-encoding;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amzn-fragment-acknowledgment-required;x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type;x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp;x-amzn-stream-name, Signature=a00b6f7ac14c766d70ef497653dbbfbfde32065260c1b26
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] DEBUG - putStreamCurlHandler(): Network thread for Kinesis Video stream: camera_1 with upload handle: 0 exited. http status: 0
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] WARN - putStreamCurlHandler(): Stream with streamHandle 21249296 uploadHandle 0 has exited without triggering end-of-stream. Service call result: 599
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] INFO - kinesisVideoStreamTerminated(): Stream 0x1443d10 terminated upload handle 0 with service call result 599.
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] DEBUG - defaultStreamStateTransitionHook(): Stream state machine retry count: 0
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] DEBUG - defaultStreamStateTransitionHook():
> KinesisVideoStream base result is [599]. Executing KVS retry handler of retry strategy type [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7mgD.png)
> 2023-04-23 22:37:48 [2780804160] DEBUG - defaultStreamStateTransitionHook(): Stream state machine retry count: 1

In AWS console, in the monitoring screen, is it possible to check that the stream is somehow connected to the server, but not correctly:

[PutMedia Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yaaU.png)

[HLS and MPEG-DASH Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7mgD.png)

How can I fix it?

Comment: please don't post images of text, post the text instead

Comment: Ok, thank you, next time I'll always post the text instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape or quote the location url, otherwise the ampersand will be interpreted by the shell as a "put in background operator":

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc \
 'location=rtsp://admin:bachir123@192.168.15.6:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0' \
 short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! \
 kvssink stream-name=YourStreamName storage-size=128 access- key="YourAccessKey" \
 secret-key="YourSecretKey
```